# Mapping Vehicle IDs between SUMO and OMNeT++ in Veins Simulations

Tags: omnet++, veins, sumo

I'm currently working on a project that integrates SUMO with OMNeT++ using Veins. After running my simulation, I understand that the vehicle IDs in OMNeT++ outputs are separate from that of SUMO and that the translation happens internally through VEINs. However, this makes  it challenging to correlate data after the simulation is concluded and I'm analyzing the different metrics produced by OMNeT++ (in the .vec and .sca files)

For example, in the .vec OMNeT++ output, the speeds/acceleration...etc of the vehicles are saved. And from the SUMO [SSM output](https://sumo.dlr.de/docs/Simulation/Output/SSM_Device.html), I get surrougate safety measure outputs. However, since the IDs between both simulators dont match, I'm not able to analyze the speed/acceleration values outputed by OMNeT++ using the information I have gathered from the SUMO SSM output.

Could anyone advise on how to modify Veins or suggest a method where I can correlate the IDs from both simulators? Ideally, I'm looking for a way to create a clear mapping/reference that allows me to easily correlate vehicles between SUMO and OMNeT++.